# No animations and effects kde plasma arch

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma, plasma5, kwin

I installed EndeavourOS (arch) with kde plasma and everything works fine, but there are no effects and animations at all. Opening a window, closing it, notifications, etc. happen instantly. In the settings in the effects there are few and no these effects. In idea it should be a package that adds these effects in the settings from where they can be included, but I do not know what. I googled and all I found were packages in AUR like "kwin-effects-yet-another-magic-lamp", "kwin-effects-minimize1" and others, but some of them are not installed and some after installation do not give anything.

The packages I found in the AUR

```
daniilskli@daniilskli-linux ~> yay -Ss kwin effect
aur/kwin-effects-sliding-notifications-git 12.949a756-1 (+0 0.00) 
    Sliding animation for notification windows
aur/kwin-effects-minimize1 1.4-1 (+0 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the minimizing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-unminimize1 1.4-1 (+0 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the unminimizing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-yet-another-magic-lamp-git 4.1.2.r0.g1e38dd1-1 (+0 0.00) 
    Just Yet Another Magic Lamp effect. (Git version)
aur/kwin-effects-cube-git 1.0.0.r0.3606d40-1 (+1 0.19) 
    Desktop cube effect for KWin
aur/kwin-effects-disappear1 1.4.1-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the disappearing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-appear1 1.3.1-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the appearing of windows
aur/kwin-effect-osdclock-git 20190925.e1479a0-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that displays clock at the corner of the screen
aur/kwin-effects-appear3 1.4-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the appearing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-disappear2 1.4-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the disappearing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-appear2 1.3-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the appearing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-disappear3 1.5-1 (+1 0.00) 
    KWin effect that animates the disappearing of windows
aur/kwin-effects-burn-my-windows-git r640.bb44d4b-1 (+2 0.40) 
    Disintegrate your windows with style.
aur/kwin-effect-shaders-git 159.ref9f7e8-1 (+2 0.24) 
    KDE Plasma / KWin desktop effect aimed at adding post processing effects to video games.
aur/kwin-effect-xrdesktop-git 0.14.0.r0.g3e85e5b-1 (+3 0.00) 
    xrdesktop effect for KWin.
aur/kwin-effect-shapecorners-git r14.4f545f9-3 (+4 0.00) 
    KWin effect to round the corners of windows.
aur/lightlyshaders-git r72.ea8187d-1 (+5 0.24) 
    Round corners and outline effect for KWin
aur/kwin-effects-blur-respect-rounded-decorations-git r13.ab7cd99-1 (+5 0.77) 
    A fork of the kwin blur effect that solves the corners bug.
aur/kwin-effects-yet-another-magic-lamp 5.25.0-1 (+6 0.00) 
    Just Yet Another Magic Lamp effect
aur/kwin-effects-sliding-notifications 1.3.0-1 (+7 0.30) 
    Sliding animation for notification windows
aur/kwin-scripts-forceblur 0.6.1-1 (+7 0.90) 
    Force-enable blur effect to user-specified windows
```